# Retrieve first hour in daylight savings change - GNU date

Tags: date, coreutils

Last weekend most of Western Europe shifted back one hour - there were two instances of `2017-10-29T02:00`.

To translate the time into UTC I can use GNU date:

```
$ date -d 'TZ="Europe/Rome" 2017-10-29 02:00'
Sun Oct 29 01:00:00 UTC 2017
```

This returns the time in CET (ie the second 2am). How do I get `date` to return `Sun Oct 29 00:00:00 UTC 2017` (the first 2am - CEST)?

Info:

```
$ date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.21
```

Comment: Actually, CEST ended on October 29, at 3:00 AM. So, 2 AM CET was 3 AM CEST.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - I thought that’s what I said. At 3am the clocks went back an hour to 2am - ie two 2 AMs

Comment: Did you try `date -u` ?

Comment: You are saying you get _Sun Oct 29 01:00:00 UTC 2017_ as output of `date -d 'TZ="Europe/Rome" 2017-10-29 02:00'` and you would want to get _Sun Oct 29 00:00:00 UTC 2017_, which is two hours earlier than the input. That is not just changing from CEST to CET or vice versa. On October 29, 2017, 2:00 AM CEST is 2:00 AM CEST, and 2:00 AM CET is  3:00 AM CEST.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Yes I want to change UTC to Europe time - having `date` translate both hours (2am CEST and 2am CET) not just the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time `TZ="Europe/Rome" 2017-10-29 02:00` is ambiguous since this translates to two different UTC times, `00:00` and `01:00`.

How to make date return both is to specify the exact timezone itself, eg

```
$ date -ud 'TZ="Europe/Rome" 02:00:00 10/29/2017 CEST'
Sun Oct 29 00:00:00 UTC 2017
$ date -ud 'TZ="Europe/Rome" 02:00:00 10/29/2017 CET'
Sun Oct 29 01:00:00 UTC 2017
```

However this means you have to work out the timezone outside the date command.

Answer (score 1):

The reference for timezone changes is `zdump`:

```
$ /usr/sbin/zdump -v -c 2017,2018 Europe/Rome
Europe/Rome  -9223372036854775808 = NULL
Europe/Rome  -9223372036854689408 = NULL
Europe/Rome  Sun Mar 26 00:59:59 2017 UTC = Sun Mar 26 01:59:59 2017 CET isdst=0
Europe/Rome  Sun Mar 26 01:00:00 2017 UTC = Sun Mar 26 03:00:00 2017 CEST isdst=1
Europe/Rome  Sun Oct 29 00:59:59 2017 UTC = Sun Oct 29 02:59:59 2017 CEST isdst=1
Europe/Rome  Sun Oct 29 01:00:00 2017 UTC = Sun Oct 29 02:00:00 2017 CET isdst=0
Europe/Rome  9223372036854689407 = NULL
Europe/Rome  9223372036854775807 = NULL
```